# Как добавить файл в архив? Perl

Tags: perl, zlib

Выборка из базы сохраняется в файл на сервере и надо этот файл пожать с помощью Compress::Zlib и перекинуть по почте.
Такое получается, но не совсем так как хочется. В архиве file.gz сохраняется файл, но без расширения .txt .

```
use Compress::Zlib;
my $file = './file.txt';
my $gzfile = './file.gz';

open(FILE,$file) or die "$!";
    my @lines = <FILE>;
    my $gz = gzopen($gzfile, 'wb');
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        my $byteswritten = $ gz-> gzwrite ($line);
    }
    $gz->gzclose();
close(FILE);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно заархивировать файл Zlib'ом.

Comment: Zlib сжимает только сами данные, в архиве не содержится метоинформация, такая как изначальное имя файла. Что бы после разархивирования стандартными средствами файл был с расширением, это расширение надо включать в имя самого архива перед gz. т.е. `$gzfile = './file.txt.gz';`

Comment: P.S. не стоит считывать весь файл в массив, если он большой может не хватить памяти. лучше архивировать по мере чтения файла, т.е. делать цикл вида `while(<FILE>)`

Comment: Большое спасибо, Mike, вы очень помогли. Переписал код и он работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Товарищ [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) помог. Большое ему спасибо.

```
use Compress::Zlib;
my $file = './file.txt';
my $gzfile = './file.txt.gz';    
open(FILE,$file) or die "$!";
    my $gz = gzopen($gzfile, 'wb');
    while(<FILE>){
        my $byteswritten = $ gz-> gzwrite ($_);
    }
    $gz->gzclose();
close(FILE);
```